# Python get parent class

Tags: python, class, object, oop

I have a Maze class, and I have a MazeTilePlacer (MTP) class. The MTP class instances will be created inside the Maze class, and need access to a variable named emptytiles in the maze class, defined as `self.emptytiles = []`. How can I access the parent object from the MTP instance to access this variable?

Comment: Send `self.emptytiles` into your `MazeTilePlacer` class's `__init__` method? (`parent` has a special meaning in object oriented programming and is about inheritance; this is not a case where inheritance should be used)

Comment: This will work, thanks! Also sorry about the terms. However, I do want multiple instances running at the same time, with the emptytiles list updating automatically.

Comment: Then giving each `MazeTilePlacer` a reference to the same dict/list will work just fine.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: By sending it in through `__init__` when creating the tile placers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this by giving each instance of `MazeTilePlacer` a reference to the same `emptytiles` list as your `Maze` object has. The `Maze` object can then delegate the responsibility of placing tiles to the other objects.

```
class Maze:
    def __init__(self):
        self.emptytiles = []

    def place_tiles(self):
        placer = MazeTilePlacer(emptytiles=self.emptytiles)
        placer.do_placements()


class MazeTilePlacer:
    def __init__(self, emptytiles):
        self.emptytiles = emptytiles

    def do_placements(self):
        self.emptytiles.append('Another tile my Sir')


maze = Maze()
maze.place_tiles()
print(maze.emptytiles)
```

If you want to have multiple tile placers, you can all give them the same reference for emptytiles. If you need these to run in parallel and manipulate the emptytiles structure in a thread safe manner (i.e. where you need to have multiple accesses without anyone changing the structure under you - for example pop, do something, then append without something being popped or appended in between) you'll have to wrap it in a lock.